# OpenCV: Panorama stitching - Ignore part of image

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I use this code to stitch images together (I'm new to OpenCV):

```
cv::Mat stitch (vector<Mat>& images)
{
    imgs = images;
    Mat pano;
    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(try_use_gpu);
    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano);

    if (status != Stitcher::OK)
        {
        cout << "Can't stitch images, error code = " << int(status) << endl;
            //return 0;
        }
    return pano;
}
```

Is there any way to have OpenCV ignoring a part of an image? Let's say I want to stitch two images together but I don't want it to calculate a square in the middle of the image.

The reason for this is I want to be able to take a photo of a person two times, then merge/stitch those two images into one, but ignore the person.

Is that doable?

Answer (score 1):

A not efficient solution could be to specify portions of image around the region that you want to ignore. Make sure the images have enough overlapping pixels for stitching. Then send all those images to the opencv stitcher.

If the ignoring region is a rectangle, you can cover the surrounding area with 2-4 rectangles depending the ignoring region.

For example the image below could be part of a panorama. You can ignore the black region and add others to stitcher's input vector.
[image: ignore black rectangle and send others to stitcher]